# Getting the value of PrimaryKey in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

My database is something like this

```
=== Group ===
id(Pk)
member_id(Fk)
description

=== Member ===
id(Pk)
firstname
lastname
```

Now I am going to define Member in Groups controller. So there I have defined the Member as like

```
$members = Members::model()->findAllByPk(array('id','condition'=>'Group=member_id','params'=>array('member_id'=>$member)));
```

But it is not working and showing error `Trying to get property of non-object`.Can someone tell me how to make that condition satisfy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well seems like you are passing invlaid arguments. See [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByPk-detail). The first argument should be id (or array of ids), the second condition (or criteria object) and then bound parameters.

Comment: what about findByPk()..Will be it more fruitful?

Comment: If you need to find only one record by its PK then you should use `findByPk`.

Comment: Ok..But here I want to show all records by its Pk.Then I have to use findAllByPk().Can You tell me what should be the condition here. I have tried many times but not got any good result.